# International F1 students applying for Canada to visit relatives

Tags: visas, canada, f1-visas

I'm an International Student currently studying in US. I would like to know if I can apply for a Canadian  tourist visa. If so, what are the documents required and what is the procedure to get a visa?

Answer (score 1):

You are eligible for a Canadian Tourist Visa and mostly likely you will be granted with 10 years of multiple entry visa or multiple entry visa till the expiry of your currently passport (whichever is earlier).

Documents vary from person to person like from which passport you hold, whether you have any multiple citizenships, your current status, etc.

Please check [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp).